# Is it possible to add a Leaflet Layer Search

Tags: javascript, search, leaflet, gis, layer

Alright so I've been working on a custom version of leaflet and is currently pretty advanced compared to it's stock counterpart. The problem with it is however that some core functionality isn't required in most custom versions of Leaflet. My problem here is, is it possible to add a search algorithm to the layer control to search for specific layers.

I've tried several plugins that don't immediately search for layers and tried to rewrite them so it works for layers. I've also got the plugin that groups all  layers in an expandable group. I'm not the best at google searches but I can't find an answer to this problem anywhere.

Since it's part of police software I can't write any code here without permission, due to the dutch laws (even if it doesn't contain crucial code).

I hope someone can help me with this issue, since it's a huge part of this piece of software. I'll have over 200 layers. They might already be grouped but searching is way nicer and faster in some occasions.

Just post some examples or links below that might work. Thanks for helping in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your place, I would add all layers to [layers-control](https://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control/) and leave only the most important ones visible on the map.
I would also add input to the layer-control and searchable in the DOM. I would probably approach this problem in this way.

[image]